# Synchronizing data between Hadoop and PostgreSql using SymmetricDs

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, symmetricds

I'm using Hadoop to store the data of our application. How can I synchronize data between PostgreSql and Hadoop? I 'm using SymmetricDS as the replication tool.

Answer (score 1):

If hadoop only copies data from PostgreSQL and no updates are done on the hadoop site, try using sqoop - simple database into hadoop import tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use SymmetricDS you can implement an IDatabaseWriter.  Here is an example of writing to MongoDB.  https://github.com/JumpMind/symmetric-mongo